# PHP preg_replace if number is bigger then 4 digits in phone number

Tags: php, regex

I have made function to replace the number in string, but it replaces all numbers, I want to make it work if number in string is above 4 digits,

```
function remove_details($string) {
        $patterns = array();
        $patterns[0] = '/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)/';
        $patterns[1] = '/([0-9]+[\- ]?[0-9]+)/';
        $replacements = array();
        $replacements[0] = '*****';
        $replacements[1] = '*****';
        $descf = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
            return $descf;
    }
```

Here all digits are removed are replaced by * in string, i want to replace if digits in string is more then 4, if digits are less then 4 then keep it, So other numbers won't replaced except the phone numbers.

Comment: Please show sample input and the expected output.

Comment: Input: "random text 123454" Output : "randrom text *****" Expected Input: "random text 012345456789" output: "random text ****" Only replace if number is more than 4 digit, else keep it as it is, becuse phone numbers are more than 6+ digits, i don't want to remove important numbers except phone numbers.

Comment: Your comment does not help in any manner. Show us what the code is expected to do because it looks like you are also looking to remove emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a short script which handles numbers as you describe:

```
$string = "random text 123454";
$pattern = "/\d{5,}/";
$descf = preg_replace($pattern, "*****", $string);
echo $descf;
```

Note that it only replaces numbers consisting of four or more digits in the input string with five stars.  I have not checked your email regex logic, and that could have problems too.

Comment: Bigger than 4 digits... this includes 4 digit numbers as well.

Answer (score 0):

No need for regex.
You can use substr, strlen and str_pad to do the same.
Generally regex uses more memory and performance to the same if it's a simple task like this.

```
$phone = 123456789;

Echo substr($phone, 0,4) . Str_pad("", strlen($phone)-4,"*");
// 1234*****
```

https://3v4l.org/CPJ52

Comment: The string isn't a one number string, this is a description box, where there will be 5000 characters, here in this whole string needed to remove mobile numbers.

Comment: If there is 5000 characters then how do you know it's a phone number and not a normal number?

Comment: That's why i want to remove number when its 4+ digit, else keep the number

Answer (score -1):

```
function remove_details($string) {
        $patterns = array();
        $patterns[0] = '/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)/';
        $patterns[1] = '/([0-9]+[\- ]?[0-9]+)/';
        $replacements = array();
        if(strlen($string)>4)
        {
            $replacements[0] = '*****';
            $replacements[1] = '*****';
            $descf = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
        }
        $descf = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);

            echo $descf;
    }
```